# Can't push to git bare repository on windows

Tags: git, msysgit, git-push

I am playing with GIT on windows. Installed msysgit (latest version) and seems everything look good. I have created bare repository on my c:/repo folder which I had clone to c:/repoclone/ with following command:

```
git clone git://localhost/repo
```

To enable git protocol I run another git-bash window with following command.

```
git daemon --export-all --enable=receive-pack
```

Cloned it correctly. Basically I want c:/repoclone/repo will be my working directory and changes I want to push at my bare repository at c:/repo. Pulling seems work fine for me but whenever trying to push data it seems keep processing without any kind of error.

Once manually break daemon command I got following error.

```
fatal: sha1 file '<stdout>' write error: Invalid argument
fatal: read error: Invalid argument
error: failed to push some refs to 'git://localhost/repo'
```

Any idea.

Comment: What `git remote -v` shows in your `c:/repoclone/repo`? What exact command are you using to push to `c:/repo`? Try first a `git push origin master` and see if it stalls as well.

Comment: git remote -v shows   
'origin git://localhost/repo (fetch)'
'origin git://localhost/repo (push)'

git push origin master command give same result
    Counting objects: 3, done.
    Writing objects: 100% (3/3)
But keep processing at writing statement
On git daemon bash I got following log..
[77552] Ready to rumble
[45740] Connection from 10.0.0.11:50875
[45740] Extended attributes (10 bytes) exist <host=cf9>
[45740] Request receive-pack for '/repo'
[45740] fatal: write error: Invalid argument

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am never able to find solution of above question and found that many people has same kind of issue but no proper solution. I drop idea for GIT protocol instead start using git over HTTP. 
http://gitblit.com is really nice solution for work over HTTP.

Hope this help.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, and for the (very interesting) gitlib link.

Answer (score 0):

I had sam issue on `TortoiseGIT` every time when I was trying push to repository.
Finally I used `--force` option which solved my problem

Answer (score -1):

I've seen this when there is no space left on the host of the bare repository. Free up some space then try again.